# Jest test runs indefinitely when all tests are included

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, preact, testing-library

##### Context:

I'm using Jest (v26.6.3) with Testing Library (@testing-library/preact, v2.0.1)

The test file includes 5 tests. Each works in isolation, and the test runs fine if I include 4/5 tests (doesn't matter which 4 tests).

No errors or failure messages are shown, but the test will run indefinitely when all 5 tests are included (I accidentally left it running in the background for ~5 hours at one point).

##### What I've tried:

I have a beforeEach in the describe block mocking the necessary calls, and calling `jest.clearAllMocks()`

In addition, I've tried:

- Using `jest.setTimeout(20000)` in the describe block and beforeEach
- Calling `cleanup()` from Preact Testing Library in a beforeEach and afterEach
- Calling `jest.resetAllMocks` in the beforeEach
- Running `npm run test [test file name] --forceExit --detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot (this command also runs indefinitely)

Comment: Have you tried to split your tests across different specs? Does it still happen?

Comment: @Yaroslavm, that did the trick — I kept 3/5 tests in the existing file and moved the two bigger tests to separate files. Worked great, thanks for the help.